# Nothing happens when I submit payment form using Django-paypal

Tags: python, django, paypal

I am developing a website with Django and I need a payment process. I decided to use django-paypal. So I followed these instructions : [django-paypal documentation](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pro/index.html)

Here is my views.py :

```py
@login_required
def buy_item(request):
    item = { 
            "amt": "1.00",
            "inv": "inventory",         # unique tracking variable paypal
            "cancelurl": "https://mywebsite.com/cancel_url/",  # Express checkout cancel url
            "returnurl": "https://mywebsite.com/return_url/"}  # Express checkout return url

    ppp = PayPalPro(
              item=item,                            # what you're selling
              payment_template="payment.html",      # template name for payment
              confirm_template="confirmation.html", # template name for confirmation
              success_url="/success/",              # redirect location after success
              nvp_handler=nvp_handler)
    return ppp(request)

def nvp_handler(nvp):
    # This is passed a PayPalNVP object when payment succeeds.
    # This should do something useful!
    pass
```

I also added the template files (payement.html and confirmation.html).

I did also all settings configuration.

The problem is that when I fill my form and submit it, nothing happens. The page is reloaded but nothing is done with the payment.

Would someone know what am I doing wrong ? Is it better to use another package for payment processing with Django or someone has a successful code using this package ?

Comment: can you edit your question with more details, such as what is the URL config, and what is the URL the template tries to hit when you click on the button ?

Comment: I tried to identify the URL I tried to hit using developer tools but I didn't succeed, it was quite strange. And concerning my URL config, it was like in the documentation and I just added also the return and cancel url

I decided to use Braintree as I needed a quick solution to my problem and it's now working now.

Thanks for the help !